# Converting STL file to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, 3d

The following website (http://quotes.rapidprototype.com.au/upload/) converts an uploaded STL file to an image (.png). How can I achieve the same functionality in .net?  Please help me if it is possible with .net.

Comment: This is far too broad a question. Do you need help with file uploading? With conversion from STL to .png? With creating a web site? Start building the pieces and when you get stuck on a _specific_ issue and you can't find a solution _after trying to research the problem yourself_, then ask here. Be prepared to explain what you have tried and why it didn't work. See the [help page on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I am searching for a free /open source code for implementing the similar functionality for converting stl file to png in .net. Please provide a good if available.

Comment: I doubt there's anything available to do exactly what you describe. I'd start by looking at some of the open-source STL viewer programs (easily found via a Google search) and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: did you find any stl to png converter?

Comment: That was a suggestion for you to do the looking, not a commitment to do the looking myself. If you search the web for "javascript stl viewer" you'll quickly find several open-source projects that you might be able to use as a starting point. Don't expect to find an stl-to-png converter; I don't know that anyone's implemented such a thing except as part of a larger stl program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/More-3D-with-the-Helix-3D-Toolkit-for-WPF

•Import •3D Studio files (.3ds) 
•Lightwave files (.lwo) 
•Wavefront files (.obj) 
•StereoLithography files (.stl)

Comment: I think the toolkit can be used with MVC application only. Is it possible to use with asp.net?

Comment: it's a wpf lib,  it can run in web, 1,var importer = new ModelImporter(); ,2 set the Wpf Light , 3, Render a Stream or a file

Answer (score 0):

This library do exactly what you were looking for. Is in Node.js but maybe you can integrate it to your App in some way.

[Stljs](https://github.com/cubehero/stljs)